# Xcode: How to have shared code (i.e. framework) between main project and plugin bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

In my project I had two targets, 1) The main application which loads 2) a bundle of plugins.  I have started to have objects which need to be available in both targets, so naively tried to compile them separately in each target (producing warnings about having different implementations: Class X is implemented in both Y and Z. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.)

To solve this I decided to create a framework, so I added a framework, but I don't know how to make it so that a) both the main app and bundle access the framework (via the compiled framework, and not just through the headers in the project), and so the framework is compiled when I run the project.

If you know how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Create a new framework in the project , copy all the shared code over.
   In the main header of the framework, include the headers of all the shared code.
2. Build the framework  to test it builds (e.g. select the scheme of the framework and click play)
3. Go to the Build Phases of both the Application and the Plugin Bundle and add the framework to ‘target dependencies’ and ‘Link binary with libraries’
4. To include the frameworks stuff in code in the app and bundle, just use the main header, and use <> rather than “" e.g if your framework was called Foo use #import

When it comes to deploying, there might have to be some fiddling with where the framework gets installed, currently it gets put alongside the app itself, rather than inside, but I will probably fix that later :)